# IE Images Issue With Subdomains

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am developing a basic site on a subdomain. I have an image in the header which shows fine on Google Chrome but on IE8 it is not showing the image.

The image SRC is http://subdomain.domain.com. The only think I can think of is that IE8 is trying to add a "www" to the image link like http://www.subdomain.domain.com/images/image.jpg and no browser can find this.

Anybody else have a solution to this?

EDIT - HERE IS THE CODE I'M USING

```
 <div id="header">
 <a href="http://subdomain.domain.co.uk"><img src="http://subdomain.domain.co.uk/images/theLogo.jpg" width="300px" />
 </a>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: I often use subdomains to serve static content and never had this kind of problem with IE8.

Comment: Did you check it out in dev tools? Hit F12 and see if it shows up and what the path is?

Comment: Hmm, I have tried with static and relative urls by the way...

Comment: Ahh checked with with F12 and the URL is correct...

Comment: can you paste particular `<img>` tag here?

Comment: Hi, sorry it is a JPG file not PNG

Answer (score 1):

When you open a Web page, the .PNG images in that page may not be displayed (in Internet Explorer). Instead, a red X, or a placeholder, may appear in place of the images. However, all other image file types may display correctly in Internet Explorer.
This problem may be seen after installing a third-party application, which may have altered the file class and MIME settings for the PNG file type. To resolve the problem, look [this link](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/202/1/PNG-images-are-not-displayed-on-Web-sites-in-Internet-Explorer.html).
Or using .jpg image.

More info:
1.[IE8 not displaying images (red x) … sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188203/ie8-not-displaying-images-red-x-sometimes)
2.[IE8 wont display .PNG images](https://superuser.com/questions/406434/ie8-wont-display-png-images)

**Adding More Information**
1.[Images don't show up in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989138/images-dont-show-up-in-ie8):Have you tried not including a closing tag for ? According the spec, it's not supposed to have one.  by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242043/mike)
2.[Image won't show up in IE8, only in Chrome or Firefox or IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555877/image-wont-show-up-in-ie8-only-in-chrome-or-firefox-or-ie9):IE8 seems to have a problem with img tags where the width attribute and the css "max-width" attribute is set... maybe just remove on of them. by [Dominik Kirschenhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555877/image-wont-show-up-in-ie8-only-in-chrome-or-firefox-or-ie9)

Comment: Hi, sorry there was a typo in the original. The image is JPG not PNG. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably served with an incorrect [MIME-type](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/definitions/mimetype.html). To determine if your image is served with the correct MIME-type, do the following:

1. Open up your web page in Google Chrome.
2. Press `F12` to open the developer tools.
3. Open the [image: Network] tab.
4. Press `F5` to reload the page.
5. Look for the name of your image in the [image: Name / Path] column.
6. If you've found your image, look in the [image: Type] column in the same row.
7. The value in the column [should be `image/jpg`](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/).
8. If it has any other value, your server is not configured correctly.
9. You should look for instructions on configuring MIME types correctly for the type of server you're using. For example, if you're using Apache you can try searching *[MIME type Apache](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=mime%20type%20apache)*.